# Undeclared identifier, in a node class

Tags: c++, class, methods, nodes, undeclared-identifier

I have 2 files: Node.h, Node.cpp,

In Node.h, I create the prototype for the Node class. In the prototype I create a string array 'name'. In the Node.cpp class, I tried to use a function that gives 'name' a value, but i keep getting undeclared identifier even though i identified 'name' in Node.h

node.h

```
#include "iostream"
#include "string.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"

template<class T>
class Node{

        char name[256];
        bool useable; 


    public:
        //Constructors
        Node();
        Node(const T& item, Node<T>* ptrnext = NULL);

        T data;
        //Access to next Node
        Node<T>* nextNode();
        //List modification
        void insertAfter(Node<T>* p);
        Node<T>* deleteAfter();
        Node<T>* getNode(const T& item, Node<T>* nextptr = NULL);
        //Data Retrieval
        char *getName();
        void *setName(char[]);
        bool isUsable();





};
```

node.cpp

```
#include "Node.h"

//Default Constructor
template<class T>
Node<T>::Node(){

}

//This constructor sets the next pointer of a node and the data contained in that node
template<class T>
Node<T>::Node(const T& item,Node<T>* ptrnext){
    this->data = item;
    this->next = ptrnext;
}

//This method inserts a node after the current node
template<class T>
void Node<T>::insertAfter(Node<T> *p){
    //Links the rest of list to the Node<T>* p
    p->next = this->next;

    //Links the previous node to this one
   this-> next = p;
}

//This method deletes the current node from the list then returns it.
template<class T>
Node<T> * Node<T>::deleteAfter(){

    Node<T>* temp = next;

    if(next !=NULL){
        next = next->next;
    }

    return temp;
}

template<class T>
Node<T> * getNode(const T& item, Node<T>* nextptr = NULL){
    Node<T>* newnode; //Local pointer for new node
    newNode = new Node<T>(item,nextptr);
    if (newNode == NULL){
        printf("Error Allocating Memory");
        exit(1);
    }
    return newNode;

}

void setName(char input[256]){
    strncpy(name,input,sizeof(name));

}
```

Comment: You have declared a member function `Node::setName` in the class definition, but you've never actually implemented it. Instead, you are trying to implement a standalone, non-member function `::setName`. That function doesn't have any particular knowledge of or access to members of `Node`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see three things immediately wrong with the following code.

```
void setName(char input[256]){
    strncpy(name,input,sizeof(name));
}
```

1. You did not provide the class name.  This is therefore declaring a static function, and not a class member.  You also forgot to do this on your `getNode` function.
2. You left out the template statement.
3. You put a template implementation in a cpp file.  Be aware that you cannot compile the cpp file as an object -- it must be included in a header, or you can ditch the file altogether and move your implementation into your header.

Comment: Another problem is that `strncpy` does not null-terminate the string if the input is too long

Comment: True but that's nothing to do with compile errors, and besides the supplied string buffer is the same size as that stored in the class.

Comment: I have a third file, but it wasn't related to the problem so I didn't include it.
But the implementation is in a header on that fail